# Trying to access method from other script; getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: unity, c#

Is this an issue with the syntax or something deeper?

There is a method `Pause();` which I'm trying to access from a different script `MyScript`.

Here is the code (I deleted out the irrelevant code):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Other.Components;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    CharacterMovement _characterMovement;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        _characterMovement.Pause();
    }

}
```

This is giving me an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. Could this be syntax or something deeper? Thanks.

Comment: You never assign to _characterMovement, so it is not initialized to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Make `CharacterMovement _characterMovement;`public:

(like this)
`public CharacterMovement _characterMovement;`

And then in the Inspector, drag the object that has CharacterMovement script attached to it.